# How to put data so that it does not disappear when using Hive typeadapter box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am using a type adapter box and having trouble putting data now.

For example, when I create a "Person" class with name, age, and address fields and generated an adapter,

The way to put data in the 'id1' key of the 'Person box' is as follows. (assuming open and get the box)

`put.box('id1', Person(name: 'john'));`

Or like this.

`put.box('id2', Person(name: 'aa', age: 10));`

However, if you do the above, the previously stored values ​​of age or address(which are not saved fields in that code) appear to be deleted. Like the 'set' method in Firestore without the 'merge'

Is there a way to update only the 'name' value so that the 'age' and 'address' values ​​are not deleted like the 'update' method in Firestore?

I have tried to find any method like an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from the documentation that shows how to update only the person's age.

```dart
var box = await Hive.openBox('myBox');

var person = Person()
  ..name = 'Dave'
  ..age = 22;

box.add(person);

print(box.getAt(0)); // Dave - 22

person.age = 30;
person.save();

print(box.getAt(0)) // Dave - 30
```

But before you update the `Person` you need to initialize it from the box and then update it. Maybe you update the `Person` with new data without initialized age or and the rest.

Comment: Woow i really appreciate for ur contribution!!
Actually I initialize the class and box but I knew that only 'put' and 'add' are the method which can change or add data. 

the way u write above is,
get the value -> change each variable value, right?
thank you so much